# scp files from particular remote folder in parallel

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, scp

I want to scp files from `machineA` into my `machineB` and this is how I am doing it. I am copying bunch of files one by one from `primary` folder of `machineA` to `primary` folder of `machineB` and `secondary` folder of `machineA` to `secondary` folder of `machineB`.

```
trinity@machineB:~$ scp trinity@machineA:/data01/primary/* /data01/primary/
trinity@machineB:~$ scp trinity@machineA:/data02/secondary/* /data02/secondary/
```

Is there any way by which I can copy multiple files in parallel? Like five files at a time from a folder? So instead of copying one files at a time, I want to copy five files from primary or secondary folders respectively?

Basically I want to copy whatever is there in primary and secondary folders of `machineA` into `machineB` parallely instead of doing sequentially. I mean I can setup some limit like copy 5 files at a time.

I also have GNU Parallel installed on my box if I can use that. I tried below command on `machineB` as it is but it doesn't work and it gives error. I was expecting that it should copy 5 files in parallel at a time until everything gets copied from that folder.

```
ssh machineA 'parallel -j 5 scp {} machineB:/data01/primary/ ::: /data01/primary/*'
```

Below is the error I see:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
lost connection
```

And I can ssh just fine from machineB to machineA without any issues. Anything wrong with my parallel syntax? What is the best way by which I can copy five files in parallel from a remote folder until everything gets copied from it? All my file name starts with `file_somenumber.dat`

Comment: You're running scp on machineA. Ensure you can ssh from machineA to machineB.

Comment: I was running that command from `machineB`. And you are saying I should run from machineA instead? yeah I can ssh from machineA to machineB just fine.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
ssh machineA 'parallel --dry-run -j 5 scp {} machineB:/data01/primary/ ::: /data01/primary/*'
```

It will print a bunch of scp lines.

Take one of those and do:

```
ssh machineA 'scp ...'
```

Do you have to enter a password?

Comment: let me confirm one thing.. Am I supposed to run above command from `machineB` or `machineA`? As of now I am running from `machineB`. Yes I have to enter a password before it can work. Can I not type my password once and then it will take for all the iteration?

Comment: Look at `ssh-agent`, `ssh-copy-id`, and `sshpass` for ways to get around that. You need the command to work without entering password for GNU Parallel to work.